# Please refine: Follow scroll but sticky on top

Tags: jquery, scroll, sticky

i have accomplished what i was trying to do: make an element follow the mousescroll. If you'd scroll down fast the element would get out of sight for a while and then follow the scroll back to its original position. Here is a first Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s4Tsy/

I also accomplished to make the element stick to the top. If we scroll fast now it never gets out of sight. Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aRnAe/

My Question is: Can this be done more elegantly? I am sure this code is clumsy. I am a novice and want to learn.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el=$('#scrolldiv');
    var originalelpos = el.offset().top;
    var scrolltimer;
    //run on scroll
     $(window).scroll(function(){
        var el=$('#scrolldiv'); // important! (local)
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var currentpos = el.offset().top;
        if(windowpos>=currentpos)
        {
            el.addClass('scrollfixed');
        }
        else
        {
            var finaldestination = windowpos+originalelpos;
            el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination},2500);
        }
        clearTimeout(scrolltimer);
        scrolltimer = setTimeout(afterScroll, 100);
     });
     function afterScroll() {
        currentpos = el.offset().top;
        windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentpos <= windowpos) {      
            el.removeClass('scrollfixed');
            el.css({top: windowpos });
            finaldestination = windowpos+originalelpos;
            el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination},1000);
        }
    } 
});
```

kind regards,
Stephan

Comment: you should also add another condition in case the user scrolls up fast, you lose sight of the scrolldiv, you will get a warning for the first scroll as your scrolltimer is undefined and you are trying to clear it, assign an empty function timeout or just add a flag for the first time as in if (v == false) means it is first time then change it to true  and clear on the true state only .. other than that I think you did a great job .. regards

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the clearing of the undefinded timer. But what ever i try i don't get the second condition working that would stick the div to the bottom. I know it would have to be if(currentpos >= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - el.height() ) but i can't apply a proper class.

Comment: here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/aRnAe/1/ ,, if you can notice it is not perfect as the div's bottom is not exactly to the bottom of the page, that is due to the class itslef, I think that's still fine at least you can't lose sight of it :).

Comment: You're awesome! {top: 90%} why didn't i think of that. I changed line 34 in your code, so it would work when slow-scrolling too. It's done and useable now. Thnak you so much! Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5wM3/

Comment: btw you can minimize calculations by assigning repeated calculations to local variables and reuse them when needed .. that's if you are looking for performance .. :)

Comment: + for the fun I had from this :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result.

**[>> A jsfiddle of the code below](http://jsfiddle.net/H5wM3/)**

I take CME64's word for it that the code is ok.

***Script***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var el = $('#scrolldiv');
    var originalelpos = el.offset().top;
    var scrolltimer;
    //run on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var currentpos = el.offset().top;
        if (windowpos >= currentpos) {
            el.addClass('scrollfixed');
        } else  if(currentpos >= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - el.height() ){
            el.addClass('scrollfixedBtm');
        }else{
            var finaldestination = windowpos + originalelpos;
            el.stop().animate({
                'top': finaldestination
            }, 500);
        }
        clearTimeout(scrolltimer);
        scrolltimer = setTimeout(afterScroll, 100);
    });

    function afterScroll() {
        currentpos = el.offset().top;
        windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentpos <= windowpos) {
            el.removeClass('scrollfixed');
            el.css({
                top: windowpos
            });
            finaldestination = windowpos + originalelpos;
            el.stop().animate({
                'top': finaldestination
            }, 500);
        }else if (currentpos >= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - el.height()){
            el.removeClass('scrollfixedBtm');
            el.css({
                top: (windowpos+$(window).height()-el.height())
            });
            finaldestination = windowpos + originalelpos;
            el.stop().animate({
                'top': finaldestination
            }, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

***CSS***

```
.scrollfixed {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0px !important;
}
.scrollfixedBtm {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 90% !important;
}
#scrolldiv {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #f00;
    left:0;
    top: 100px;
}
```

*** HTML *** (of course effect only visible in long scrollable pages)

```
<div id="scrolldiv"></div>
```